# Update specific octet within a IP Address Subnet

Tags: powershell

Is there is a shorter way to realise my little tricks?

`$ipsubnet` is from the following form: `X.X.X.0` and I want to add +1 to the third X e.g. `X.X.(X+1).0`

```
$tmp = $ipsubnet -replace '..$', ''
$tmp -match '.$'
$tmp2 = [int]$Matches[0]+1
$tmp =  $tmp -replace '.$', '$tmp2'
$ipsubnet = $tmp + ".0"
```

Comment: `"$([ipaddress](([ipaddress]$ipsubnet).Address + 0x10000))"` if 3rd num is less than 255

Comment: Didn't knew that type existed, thanks !

Comment: I would recommend against that if you don't know the network mask.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sm = "255.255.48.0".Split('.')
if([int]$sm[2] -lt 255) { $sm[2]=([int]$sm[2]+1).ToString(); }
$sm = $sm -join "."
$sm
```

This answer will take into consideration the max value of an octet in a subnet mask (255) in the second lines if statement. 
It also allows you to supply a basic string as your input in the first line. This can be substituted with a variable. Please not that this does not 'check' the subnet mask for validity, since only specific values can constitute a valid subnet mask.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.